# display web page inside android app and save opened web page in sd card

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating android app in flash cs6. I need to open web pages inside that app. I used webView to open web site inside my app. But the problem is I can't put anything over the stageWebView and I want the web site inside the movie clip so that I can animate the movie clip before showing the content of website. And I also want to save the web content for offline use. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can put contents over the web-view what ever the animations or pictures. As per as the content save is concerned you can take a screen shot of the whole web page problematically or save the complete web page as a PDF file so that users can read it later when internet is not available.

Also one another way is to parse the webpage contents using the [Jspup](http://jsoup.org/) library and in offline mode, create a view like webpage using these contents to give the read experience of the webpage to user. Hope it will give you the direction. Further you take a start and paste your code, we will solve the issue. Good luck!

Comment: Currently I'm using bitmap to save the screen shot. It will be a lot easier if I can open the web page inside movie clip. And I can't use PDF because web contains few interactive buttons which users have to display certain things.

Comment: Yeah its good, as saving a bitmap is quite easy rather than PDF as well.

Comment: Is there another way to open webpage inside app ? And how can we save web page ?

Comment: I've posted another way to do your work as an answer. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable cache and save your required page like this.

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );
```

Through this way your page will be saved in your local directory and in case of network nonavailability you can use that one from cache.

Comment: Is this code from java script ? I'm doing my project in flash.